# Jssor slider with nested slide + vertical thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, jssor

I would like to combine the [nested slider option](http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html) with a [vertical thumbnail](http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html). I am looking at the source code for examples image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.source.html and nested-slider.source.html and I am not sure how could I combine these two. I mean both of them do have thumbnavigator, but how would I map the thumbnavigator to the currently selected sliderhx_container?

Answer (score 0):

You can place child slider in any slide of parent slider.

```
<div id="parent_slider" ...>
    <div u="slides" ...>
        <!-- slide 1 -->
        <div>
            <div id="sliderh1_container" ...>
                <!-- content of sliderh1 -->
            </div>
            <img u="thumb" src="sliderh1_thumb.jpg" />
        <div>
        <!-- slide 2 -->
        <div>
            <div id="sliderh2_container" ...>
                <!-- content of sliderh2 -->
            </div>
            <img u="thumb" src="sliderh2_thumb.jpg" />
        <div>
        <!-- slide x -->
        <div>
            <div id="sliderhx_container" ...>
                <!-- content of sliderhx -->
            </div>
            <img u="thumb" src="sliderhx_thumb.jpg" />
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have put the thumbnavigator (you did mean this one with child slider, right?) into the parent slider (sliderh1_container), but now the slider with the nested thumbs is gone.

Comment: Any url that I can access online?